# Debian: transition from plymouth to lightdm without console text at boot time

Tags: debian, lightdm, plymouth

I am using plymouth for boot splash and lightdm as display manager on a Debian 9 (stretch) box. My aim is to have a smooth graphical transition from plymouth to lightdm with no console text in between. However, when the machine boots there is a short period of time (about a second or so) when the tty1 console login pops up:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9 <hostname> tty1
<hostname> login:
```

This does not happen when I run Ubuntu on the same hardware. How can I eliminate this switch to text mode in Debian?

EDIT

Configuring `lightdm.service` to have a [negative requirement dependency](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) on `getty@tty1.service`, i. e. adding the following snippet to the relevant `systemd` configuration (e. g. `/etc/systemd/system/lightdm.service.d/override.conf`):

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service
```

prevents the login prompt (above) to be shown, but it does **not** solve the problem of temporarily switching to text mode - a blinking underscore symbol (`_`) appears in the top left corner of the screen for a short time instead.

Answer (score 0):

Update your grub adding `vt.global_cursor_default=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.